# Setting one keymap for both Visual Studio 2017 and IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-2017

I normally use Visual Studio 2017 with C# and I am used to the Visual Studio short cuts. We recently started aa cooperation with another company and I have to also work with IntelliJ for some java projects.

In order to simplify my start with IntelliJ I wanted to use the same keymap settings for all three IDEs.

I tried:

1. changing the default settings (menu File > Settings) in IntelliJ to the Visual Studio keymap - still the shortcuts are very different from VS2017...
2. importing a .vssettings file from VS2017 into IntelliJ, however it did not work because IntelliJ is expecting a .zip file.... !?

Is there a standard way to import the VS2017 settings into IntelliJ or vice versa? I am open to import the IntelliJ settings to VS2017 if this is the only way...

Since I suppose there are other developers having the same situation I wanted to ask the community if there is a standard solution for this supported by Micsoroft and/or Jetbrains..?